# HTTP/2 RESTful server with Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, http2

I'd like to create a Java RESTful server with a HTTP/2 interface. In the past I have used [Jersey](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/) many times, and have considerable experience with it. So if I can, I'd like to stick to that. However, I struggle to find information regarding Jersey and its support of HTTP/2, but maybe I'm getting things confused here.

Would it maybe be correct to assume that it's the responsibility of *the underlying [HTTP-server](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.http)* to provide HTTP/2, not *Jersey*? Meaning, if the HTTP-server is HTTP/2-ready, Jersey will work just like before, no changes necessary.

This overview of [Grizzly's HTTP/2 support](https://javaee.github.io/grizzly/http2.html) seems to support this, if I understand it right.